# php email sending errors

Tags: php, email

Fairly new to PHP, and I'm working on a simple form,

Users enter in their information and then once it's checked to see if the information is there and not empty, then use the mail function to send it out

here is the code

I get the error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration.php on line 20

line 20 is where the mail function is

```
if (isset ($_POST['attendee']) && isset ($_POST['attending']) && isset ($_POST['message']) && isset ($_POST['contact_email']))
{

    $attendee = $_POST['attendee'];
    $attending = $_POST['attending'];
    $contact_email = $_POST['contact_email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    if(!empty($attendee) && !empty($attending) && !empty($message) && !empty ($contact_email))
        {
            $to = 'someemail@gmail.com';
            $subject = 'Wedding Information Received'.'attending';
            $body = $message;
            $headers = 'From: '.'contact_email';

            if (@mail(($to,$subject, $body, $headers))){
                echo 'Thanks for Reserving';
            } else{
                echo 'Sorry, an error occured. Please Try again     later.';
            }
        }
    else{
        echo ' All Fields are Required';
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing `@mail(($to,$subject, $body, $headers))` to just `@mail($to,$subject, $body, $headers)`

Answer (score 2):

You are using 2 `((` in front of `mail` instead `(` and  3 `)))` instead of 2 `))` at the end ...

Replace

```
  if (@mail(($to,$subject, $body, $headers))){
```

With

```
  if (@mail($to,$subject, $body, $headers)){
```

Comment: thanks that was totally it, question though, I'm getting the error message right when I launch the page in localhost....ideas why?